# How to find the last access time of a schema in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to delete all schema that have not been accessed for a month or so. The dba_users table does not contain information regarding this.

**EDITED**
Since I did not find any access dates for the schemas, I created a table for log information as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user_audit_log
( 
   user_id           VARCHAR2(15),
   session_id        NUMBER(10),
   host              VARCHAR2(20),
   logon             DATE,
   logoff            DATE,
   elapsed_minutes   NUMBER(10)
);
```

And created triggers that fire every time a schema is logged in and logged out.

```
--Trigger for login time
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
  logon_trigger
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user_audit_log VALUES
  (
     USER,
     sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID'),
     sys_context('USERENV','HOST'),
     SYSDATE,
     NULL,
     NULL
  );
END;

--Trigger for logoff time and elapsed time
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
  logoff_trigger
BEFORE logoff ON DATABASE

BEGIN
  UPDATE user_audit_log
  SET
   logoff = SYSDATE
  WHERE
   sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') = session_id;

  UPDATE user_audit_log
  SET
    elapsed_minutes = round((logoff - logon)*1440)
  WHERE
  sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') = session_id;

END;
```

These triggers store the access dates in the log table which I can use to determine when they were last accessed.

Comment: Do you want to find last time login details of your schema's??

Comment: Please define "access".   Do you mean logged in?  If so, does your application audit that activity?  What about schemas which aren't "real people" but own objects used by other users?  Presumably you don't want to zap those.

Comment: @APC Check the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

Try below ,

SQL> SELECT USERNAME,USERID,ACCOUNT_STATUS FROM DBA_USERS;

The above query sure will show all the users and their current status .
Status might be anyone of the below:

```
OPEN,EXPIRED,EXPIRED(GRACE),LOCKED(TIMED),LOCKED,EXPIRED & LOCKED(TIMED),EXPIRED(GRACE) & LOCKED(TIMED),EXPIRED & LOCKED,EXPIRED(GRACE) & LOCKED
```

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question. Please check the edited version.